# Invitation Redemption Failed - Azure DevOps Invitation to External Email Fails

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I am inviting a team member (using an external email) to contribute to one of the project in our Azure Dev Ops (Visual Studio Team Services). For some reason the team member is unable to view the project. They are getting this error.

[image]

Any suggestion to fix this ?

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen this error. But I can try to guess what it is trying to say. The user you have invited is part of an Azure AD somewhere. But somehow, when redeeming the invite, they are not signing in to that existing AAD account, but instead trying to create a username + password guest account (which would be created in a hidden AAD). But that situation should not occur...

Comment: Or, this user's domain is such that it is used in a federated AAD, but this user is not synced there.

Comment: Check if this thread give any helps:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d9c92fea-a554-4c7a-91af-30016aa35111/invitation-redemption-failed-aadb2b0001-we-canot-create-a-selfservice-azure-ad-account-for?forum=WindowsAzureAD